# Find $f^{(k)}(0)$ for $k=1,2,3,...$ Help?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, power-series

Let

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(x)}{x} & x\neq0\\
1 & x=0
\end{cases}$$

Find $f^{(k)}(0)$ for $k=1,2,3,\dotsc.$

My idea:

I was thinking of looking for a sequence of functions converging such that each function is differentiable and each of those differentiable functions is continuous, to apply the following theorem.

$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f'_{n}(x)$

But i cannot find that function, Can someone help me to solve this exercise?

Comment: Write the Taylor series for sine and divide by $x$ term by term.

Answer (score 3):

As per Cameron Williams:

---

Just notice that

$$\frac{\sin(x)}x=\frac1x\left[x-\frac1{3!}x^3+\frac1{5!}x^5-\frac1{7!}x^7+\dots\right]=1-\frac1{3!}x^2+\frac1{5!}x^4-\frac1{7!}x^6+\dots$$

Thus, we have

$$\begin{align}f(x)&=1-\frac1{3!}x^2+\frac1{5!}x^4-\frac1{7!}x^6+\dots\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!}\end{align}$$

Seeing that there are no odd powers in the Taylor expansion, we conclude that $f^{(2n+1)}(0)=0$ and likewise that $f^{(2n)}(0)=(-1)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{x} & \equiv {\sin\pars{x} \over x} =
{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic xq}\,\dd q \implies
\mrm{f}^{\mrm{\pars{k}}}\pars{0} =
{1 \over 2}\,\ic^{\mrm{k}}\int_{-1}^{1}q^{\mrm{k}}\,\dd q =
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{0} & \mbox{if} & \ds{k}\ \mbox{is}\ odd
\\[2mm]
\ds{\phantom{^{\mrm{k}/2}}\pars{-1}^{\mrm{k}/2} \over k + 1} & \mbox{if} & \ds{k}\ \mbox{is}\ even
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}